# Gridview content stretch UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it possible in xaml to make the content of the GridView stretch so that when the width of the GridView is changed, the items dispose of stretch? I tried with HorizontalContentAlignment but it does not work.

MainPage.xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="GridViewItemList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}" Margin="0,50,0,0" SizeChanged="GridViewItemList_SizeChanged">
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="Item" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF2D7496" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"/>
        <GridView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="GridView">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.Style>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

I would like, as the width of the GridView changes, that the items spread across the full width of the GridView.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want items with fixed size fill the free space in gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [`AdaptiveGridView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/AdaptiveGridView/) which is part of [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/). This control is very smart in this regard and can automatically stretch the controls as necessary so that the row is equally filled and there is no space left out on either side.